React Native, an error is showed when I try to start app on android
I installed everything for starting react native on android. The command "npx react-native doctor" shows that everyhting is fine. I have also connected an android device to my computer, and this device is shown when I input the command "adb devices".
But when I input the command "npx react-native run-android", I see this mistake: pastebin.com/SyBLbmdz (it is too long to be published here).
How to solve that?

I have understood. The problem was because of incompatible NDK version. I used 28.0.12674087, now I installed 26.1.10909125 using the command "sdkmanager", and now everything works correctly.

May be there is a problem with your setup and react native, try this:
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean --force
npm install


when I write "rm -rf node_modules", it is shown that "'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
I use Windows 10.

rm is just a delete command. Just manually delete the node_modules folder
